# Regex between elements for specific characters

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

Say I have the following String:

```
&<div>test & test & test</div><&>
```

How would I go about finding all the & in between the element tags, i.e. `></`? (doesn't have to be specific to divs)

So far I've gotten `>.*(&).*<`, but that only finds the last & in between the `></`.

For context, I eventually need to use this regex to translate certain special characters to use the appropriate escape character, but only in between the elements.

Comment: [`(?:\G(?!\A)|>)[^<&]*\K&(?=[^<]*<\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ym6kdS/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match only the `&`, use a look ahead:

```
&(?=[^<>]*</)
```

It’s not bullet proof, but will hopefully work for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `.*` expression is “greedy”. And I can’t see the slash after the final `<` symbol in your regexp.

The precise answer depends on the RE dialect you’re using (you didn’t say anything about it), but in common case, this must work:

```
>([^<&>]*(&)[^<&>]*)*</
```